# Font family style is not applying in android device?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, font-face

Hi i have tried to add font family in select option ..

My Code

```
<button class="item item-input item-select myb2"  style="height:27px;width:33%; float:left; padding-top:0px;">
    <div class="input-label" style="padding-top:0px;">
      Font
    </div>
    <select style="width:10px; padding-top:0px;" ng-change="changefont(fontss)"  ng-model="fontss">
      <option  ng-repeat="font in fonts">{{font.font}}</option>
      </select>
  </button>
```

**Not Working in Android Device**
 [image: Not Working in Android Device]

**But Working fine in web**

[image]

Comment: it's a native device control.... didn't you also wonder why the radio buttons aren't on your web version?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong in this ... but my requirement is shown in web ...

Comment: you can't control much of native controls...they are consistent across all apps for a reason....user convenience. Don't use `<select>` if you want more control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Android device, while using a `<select>` tag the native style will be displayed. To apply font changes we don't want to use `<select>` tag.